# Exception when making a call to DB and returning a List<T>

Tags: wcf

I am making a WCF service that connects to a database and return results. One out of four DataContracts works without a problem (that return an int) but the other three give me an exception (that return a List). Below the error message.

> The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException
> webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
> at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
> timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
> TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
> message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
> Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
> Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
> methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
> message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
> reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
> msgData, Int32 type)    at IReceiverService.SatList()    at
> ReceiverServiceClient.SatList()
>
> Inner Exception: The underlying connection was closed: The connection
> was closed unexpectedly.    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
> at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
> timeout)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to decorate the entities returned or the service with [known type attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx)

Comment: I checked the link and I still cant fix the error. Simply I added a  [KnowType(typeof(T))] and also I tried [knowType (name = "T")], both in the class the implements the interface (DataContract). But still it give me an error when I try to run it.

Comment: I searched and the only thing that I understand is the WCF service cant understand the type of the Table in the DB. By which it cant understand the custom types !!! If I returned any known type by the .net framework it will work with no problem ex. Int. Please tell me how can I fix this.